# Adding Array data to a list: Cannot Convert System.DirectoryInfo[] to string

Tags: c#

So basically heres my noob attempt at indexing and storing data. I made 2 lists that store directories and files from different arrays using the DirectoryInfo class.

I'm getting compiler errors at `SubDirectoriesList.Add(subdirectories);`,`DirectoryInfo[] directoryFiles = di.GetFiles(SubDirectoriesList);`, and `FilesList.Add(directoryFiles);`.

Most of them stating:

> Use of unassigned local variable. Cannot Convert
>   System.DirectoryInfo[] to string.

I've tried a few different things and it feels really close. I've reviewed a couple c# List tutorials as well but couldn't translate the super simple examples into my function.

```
        List<string> FilesList;
        List<string> SubDirectoriesList;

        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(fbd.SelectedPath);

        //GETS SUBDIRECTORIES FROM SELECTED PATH
        DirectoryInfo[] subdirectories = di.GetDirectories();
        for (int i = 0; subdirectories.Length >= 0; i++)
        {
            if (i > subdirectories.Length - 1)
            {
                break;
            }

            //ADD SUBDIRECTORIES TO LIST
            SubDirectoriesList.Add(subdirectories);
        }

        //GETS FILES FROM SUBDIRECTORIES IN LIST
        DirectoryInfo[] directoryFiles = di.GetFiles(SubDirectoriesList);
        for (int i = 0; directoryFiles.Length >= 0; i++)
        {
            if (i > directoryFiles.Length - 1)
            {
                break;
            }

            //ADD FILES TO FILES LIST
            FilesList.Add(directoryFiles);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well the error is quite obvious, you did not new up the Lists, and subdirectories are not of type string. Either have a list of whatever the subdirectory type is, or convert them to a string.

Comment: This is really trivial stuff, of creating object instance and using index inside loop. We can't possibly spoon-feed you, you have to learn the basics yourself. Good luck!

Comment: When you get this "cannot convert...error" this usually means that you are passing the wrong parameter to the method as argument. You need to read the documentation of the method in question And find out which type of parameter out needs and pass exactly such a type

Comment: My comment refers to the methods `Add` and `GetDirectories`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you were trying this:

```
List<string> FilesList = new List<string>();
List<string> SubDirectoriesList = new List<string>();

DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop));

//GETS SUBDIRECTORIES FROM SELECTED PATH
DirectoryInfo[] subdirectories = di.GetDirectories();
for (int i = 0; subdirectories.Length >= 0; i++)
{
    if (i > subdirectories.Length - 1)
    {
        break;
    }

    //ADD SUBDIRECTORIES TO LIST
    SubDirectoriesList.Add(subdirectories[i].FullName);
}

//GETS FILES FROM SUBDIRECTORIES IN LIST

//Loop all sub directory files
foreach (var fileItem in SubDirectoriesList)
{
    string[] directoryFiles =  Directory.GetFiles(fileItem);
    for (int i = 0; directoryFiles.Length >= 0; i++)
    {
        if (i > directoryFiles.Length - 1)
        {
            break;
        }

        //ADD FILES TO FILES LIST
        FilesList.Add(directoryFiles[i]);
    }

}
```

Comment: yes. perfect thank you. Instantiating the lists was easy. But I needed this example to see the foreach loop declaring the new variable and why the Directory.Info[] was not working to make a new directoryFiles array. I did not realize that I no longer was trying to use the DirectoryInfo's selected path to get the data, and instead was trying to get the data from the subdirectory array.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you just not initialized your list **SubDirectoriesList** before you tried to add.